# Want to extract the alphanumeric text with certain special characters using python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, special-characters

I have a following text which I want in a desired format using python regex

```
text = "' PowerPoint PresentationOctober 11th, 2011(Visit) to Lap Chec1Edit or delete me in â€˜viewâ€™ then â€™slide masterâ€™.'"
```

I used following code

```
reg = re.compile("[^\w']")
text = reg.sub(' ', text)
```

However it gives output as text = `"'PowerPoint PresentationOctober 11th  2011 Visit  to Lap Chec1Edit or delete me in â  viewâ   then â  slide masterâ'"` which is not a desired output.

My desired output should be `text = '"PowerPoint PresentationOctober 11th, 2011(Visit) to Lap Chec1Edit or delete me in view then slide master.'"`
I want to remove special characters except following `[]()-,.`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing the chars, you may fix them using the right encoding:

```
text = text.encode('windows-1252').decode('utf-8')
// => ' PowerPoint PresentationOctober 11th, 2011Visit to Lap Chec1Edit or delete me in ‘view’ then ’slide master’.'
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/I3vGVN)

If you want to remove them later, it will become much easier, like `text.replace('‘', '').replace('’', '')`, or `re.sub(r'[’‘]+', '', text)`.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer though it was simple as follows, thanks for replies.

```
reg = re.compile("[^\w'\,\.\(\)\[\]]")
text = reg.sub(' ', text)
```